# Coloring output in R Language

Tags: r, textcolor

Is there any way that I can change the output color in R.

Let for example

```
> y="red color"
> z=5<3
```

need some command that will print the value of y in red color, and/or value of z in red. Is it possible in simple way?

Comment: So you want it to appear colored in your console? What GUI are you using? What about lines that aren't definitions? Why is this something you *need*?

Comment: using RStudio, Tinn-R. I need this for quick decision about the analysis done.

Answer (score 1):

For general coloring of output there is a package called [colorout](http://www.lepem.ufc.br/jaa/colorout.html). It says that in order to change the color of R output you would have to rewrite the outputing functions.

It is not available on CRAN, but you can download and install it from github. Then simply load the package `library(colorout)`

If you only want specific outputs colored (instead of all R output) I guess you might try looking through the source of colorout: https://github.com/jalvesaq/colorout/blob/master/R/colorout.R and writing your own output function.

Answer (score 1):

There is a package called 'crayon' (https://github.com/gaborcsardi/crayon). It allows you coloring outputs. Unfortunately, the RStudio console can't display these colors yet.
Examples from crayon package:

```
library(crayon)
#test1
cat(blue("Hello", "world!\n"))

#test2
cat(green(
  'I am a green line ' %+%
  blue$underline$bold('with a blue substring') %+%
  ' that becomes green again!\n'
))
```