# Writing Console Virtual Terminal Sequences From R to Powershell

Tags: r, powershell

I'm trying to write colored output back to the terminal from an R script running in that terminal.  I'm working in the Windows Powershell in Rstudio on Windows 10.  It seems like the powershell supports colors, but I cannot get my outputs from R to activate the [virtual terminal sequences](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-virtual-terminal-sequences#text-formatting) needed to display them. If I use echo in the terminal, I can display the colors the way I want to:

[image: echo in powershell]

I've tried multiple ways of writing them to the terminal from within an R script, including using the popular `crayon` package, but none seem to work:

```
# test.R
library(crayon)
cat("$([char]27)[36mCyan!$([char]27)[37m\n")
cat("$([char]27)[36m", "Cyan!", "$([char]27)[37m", "\n")
cat(green("Green!"),"\
```

[image: terminal output]

Note that [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29861065/coloring-output-in-r-language) post addresses the use of color in the RStudio **console** while I'm trying to get it to work in the **terminal**, which is separate.  `Crayon` correctly outputs the colors in the console, but you can't execute a script there.
Is there a way to write lines to the terminal so that the virtual terminal sequences will work properly?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Coloring output in R Language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29861065/coloring-output-in-r-language)