# How to make a checking function in R having the same style of output as devtools::check

Tags: r, devtools

I would like to make a function checking different aspects of a complex list that is outputted by one of my functions. This is to help parametrise this function; there are a lot of parameters influencing the output, and adapting the parametrisation to have the best-fitted output implies a lot of trial and error for the user. In order to facilitate that I would like to make a 'check' function, providing different quantified and logical tests of the output. Ideally, I would like it to have the same style as the output given by `devtools::check()` or `devtools::build()`, like this:

[image]

I tried to go inside the `devtools::check()` or `devtools::build()` functions, but could not find what they use to have this kind of output. Is it possible to have it for the task I have described ?

Comment: You might find these useful: https://usethis.r-lib.org/reference/ui.html

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `cat` inside your function in this way to map and show update on the function:

```
f<-function()
{
   cat("checking for file\n")
   cat("preparing\n")
}
```

Output:

```
f()
    checking for file
    preparing
```

Differents colours and palette could be added using package [colorout](https://github.com/jalvesaq/colorout/blob/master/R/colorout.R).

This is the pattern used inside devtools package:

```
cat_rule(left = "Building", right = pkg$package, col = "cyan")
```

Comment: Oh yeah, and then I can change the colour, as mentionned in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29861065/coloring-output-in-r-language

Comment: I do wonder however how to make the exact same text colour than the `devtools::check()` function, it is not available in the 'crayon' library (https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=crayon)

Comment: Have a look here: https://github.com/jalvesaq/colorout/blob/master/R/colorout.R

Comment: I did, but this is a github package, so I suppose this is not the one used in `devtools::check()`: what I am coding will be part of a CRAN package, so using a github package will be more tricky no ?

Comment: This is the way used inside the function "check":  cat_rule(left = "Building", right = pkg$package, col = "cyan") try to use the same pattern